# how to add a stackpanel inside dynamically created button in wp7 programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to Know How to create a button in code behind which contains Stackpanel as container 
and textblock inside stackpanel as child,when i was tried to create the button it throws Null Exception in Stackpanel.Kindly help me to solve this problem.

What I've tried is:

```
foreach (var pd in Query)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    b.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    b.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    b.Height = 196;
    b.Width = 172;
    b.Margin = new Thickness(d, 0, 0, 0);
    b.Style = this.Resources["ButtonStyle1"] as Style;

    Grid st = new Grid();

    st.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    st.Width = 160;
    st.Height = 188;

    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
    tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
    tb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    tb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    tb.FontSize = 14;
    tb.Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0);
    tb.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
    tb.FontSize = 14;
    tb.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
    tb.Height = 35;

    TextBlock tb1 = new TextBlock();
    tb1.Height = 109;
    tb1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
    tb1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    tb1.FontSize = 12;
    tb1.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;

    b.Content = pd.ProductName;

    b.FontSize = 14;
    b.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

    ContentPanel.Children.Add(b);

    b.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(b_Click);

    st.Children.Add(tb);
    st.Children.Add(tb1);

    st = b.Content as Grid;

    d += 140;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: For Reference See My Code in this link [link](http://pastebin.com/VMg13DtJ)

Comment: I've added the code to your answer. Which line is throwing the exception? Anyway, in your code you're not actually using the value of `st`. I believe what you wanted to do at the end is `b.Content = st;` rather than `st = b.Content as Grid;`

Comment: Thanks a Lot It works. Previously the line b.content as grid throws Null Exception,and now that is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you're not actually using the value of st. I believe what you wanted to do at the end is `b.Content = st;` rather than `st = b.Content as Grid`